# A question about integration explanation

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am recently working on a project related to Sato-Tate conjecture and reading a few papers for that. I am stuck at a point understanding an integral . 
Kindly please have a look page 14 , the non- CM case

https://www.math.umd.edu/~pwerthei/files/papers/extremalprimes.pdf

The first step which I understood is 
1. Using the taylor's expansion (if I am right). 
2. After that I have no idea how the integration is done or if there is a mistake.

some help or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you .

Comment: There is no page 14.

Comment: Could you please write the integral in the question.

Comment: I am really soryy . I posted the wrong link https://www.math.umd.edu/~pwerthei/files/papers/extremalprimes.pdf is the correct link       page 14 , the non-CM case at the end

Comment: I have edited it in the original question also.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping the constant multipliers, the integral in question is $$\int \sqrt{1-t} + O((1-t)^{3/2})\,dt$$
The substitution $u = 1 - t$ makes this $$-\int\sqrt u + O(u^{3/2})\,du$$ which is $$-\frac 23u^{3/2} - O\left(u^{5/2}\right) = -\frac 23(1-t)^{3/2} - O\left((1-t)^{5/2}\right)$$

evaluting the first term at the limits gives
$$-0 + \frac 23\left(\frac 1{2\sqrt p}\right)^{3/2} = \frac 1{3\sqrt 2}p^{3/4}$$

Which matches their result when the $\frac {2\sqrt 2}{\pi}$ multiplier is included. A similar calculation shows why the second term is $O(p^{5/4}).$

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :). Can I ask the next step which is changing summation to integral is related with # {p<=x}  are x/logx ?

Comment: I cannot make any sense of that comment. If you have an additional concerns about this question, could you please clarify? If you have additional questions about the paper, then you should ask them in separate threads.

Comment: ok I will make another post. I DO NOT have any addtional concerns. It is just that I am trying to understand the paper step by step as I had mentioned above in the main question as well.

Comment: Okay. I Just couldn't figure out your comment. If I've answered your question here, please accept it so that this thread can be closed.

Comment: It is clear now. Thank you for your efforts :).